# What is the translation of the tome/book artifact text?

Tags: fez

Is the text supposed to translate to something useful? It doesn't appear to follow the language's conventions. How is it deciphered, and in which direction should it be read? Is its content story-related or does it answer the monolith puzzle?

[image: tome cover]

(I have ten more images of the pages themselves, but I'm afraid they'd make this thread too long.)

Comment: To all potential answerers: please only post if you have an actual solution to offer. If your answer does not actually offer what you believe to be the deciphered translation, then it will be removed. If you want to enter a *discussion* about how to attain the correct solution, please either our [chat] or use a different website; we try and avoid extended discussions here.

Comment: I and another member of XBOX360A translated the entire tome, though it appears to be gibberish: http://pastebin.com/ea2pHngu

Comment: Whatch this, they managed to translate it : http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/961239-fez/62545145

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
FROM OUT OF NOWHERE 
IMPOSSIBLE VISITORS 
OUR BENEFACTORS

WATCHING OVER US 
IN THE HIDDEN FOLDS OF SPACE 
IN FRONT OF BEHIND 

GIVE THE GOLDEN GIFT 
A DEEP REVELATION 
OUR EYES WIDE OPEN 

SHAPES TO TESSELLATE 
WITH SACRED GEOMETRY 
AN EMPIRE TO BUILD 

A NEW PERSPECTIVE 
THINGS UNSEENS BUT ALWAYS THERE 
A NEW DIRECTION 

THE HEXAHEDRON 
THE SIXTY FOUR BIT NAME OF GOD 
THE POINT OF ORIGIN 

A PATTERN A CODE 
A DEEP UNDERSTANDING 
A GATE TO THE STARS 

ALL OF TIME AND SPACE 
AND THE SPACE OUTSIDE OF SPACE 
WHERE DOES IT END
```

The tome consists of [haikus](http://www.trueachievements.com/a163598/haikus-not-epics-achievement.htm). Some were spread throughout the game—written on walls and repeated by owls. The book is read three-dimensionally, using a letter from each page in this order: 15263748. The text isn't rotated, and the translation starts in the upper-right corner and moves downwards. The decyphering technique is [described at GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/961239-fez/62556785/698288197).

Comment: I still wonder what means the 8 big letters...