# How do I find the writing in/on the FEZ Tome artifact

Tags: fez

I've seen people [translate the Tome artifact's text](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62597/what-is-the-translation-of-the-tome-book-artifact-text), but my question is: how do I even see any encoded text at all. The tome artifact just looks like a closed book. I've tried examining it in the inventory menu, and pushing every button I can think of, but it doesn't open or anything. What am I missing? All my googling just tells me the solutions, but where is the puzzle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Xbox 360, press <kbd>X</kbd> and then use the rotation trigger/buttons to flip through the pages.

Comment: Thanks. And on PC it's L-CTRL. Same as the button for grabbing.